# Screenshot Windows 7 at higher resolution

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution, screenshot, zoom

I want to take screenshots of my Windows 7 desktop at a higher resolution than my monitor size (1920*1080). Here's why: I am making a video that would need to zoom in by a scale factor of 2 at various locations of the screenshot, but taking a screenshot at 1920*1080 and zooming in makes it look pixelated.

Many people on the web have said that it simply isn't possible to display at a resolution higher than my monitor, but the point is I don't need to display it on my physical monitor.  I just want to screenshot it at a high resolution and then change the resolution back.

I'm guessing this should be the way to do it (if it's even possible):

1. Set my DPI to 200% using Control Panel > Display
2. Set my screen resolution to 3840*2160 using Control Panel > Adjust screen resolution
3. Screenshot
4. Set my screen resolution back to 1920*1080
5. Set my DPI back to 100%

The problem is that I can't do step 2 because the drop-down menu for "Resolution" doesn't have anything more than 1920*1080 as that's the highest resolution that my monitor supports.  Is there anyway this can be done (or it can't be done)?

If it is needed, I'm using Windows 7 64-bit with NVIDIA GeForce GT 555M graphics card.

Comment: This is a duplicate. I overlooked the existing question.

Comment: You can do this in almost any video player (or editor). Open the video, select a zoom factor, then take a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia Control Panel > Display > Change Resolution > press Customize

Voila!

Comment: This doesn't work for me because my Nvidia Control Panel doesn't have a "Display" button and I can't change the screen resolution anywhere on the control panel.  I suspect that I'm using a different version of the control panel.